# Need to pull data for today but date is in timestamp. How do I do this?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to pull data for today, month and year but my time in the table is in a time stamp.

Here is what I have been trying but it does not work

```
 $today = date('m-j-Y');
 $result99 = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT * FROM send_data WHERE sponsor='$login' AND checked='1' AND done='1' AND DATE(m-j-Y, post_time) = '$today' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

post_time is the field name in the table. I have also tried a lowercase date and it did not work either.

Please help on this. I tried to find in already in Stack Overflow but I either was not searching correctly or it's not here.

Comment: You could just use native MySQL functions, making it `AND DATE(post_time)=CURDATE()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use parameters in your queries.  But, apart from that, just use the built-in date/time functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM send_data
WHERE sponsor='$login' AND checked='1' AND done='1' AND
      date(post_time) = curdate()
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

If `post_time` is a Unix timestamp, then you can use `from_unixtime()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM send_data
WHERE sponsor='$login' AND checked='1' AND done='1' AND
      date(from_unixtime(post_time)) = curdate()
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Note:  There are better ways to formulate these queries if performance is an issue and you have appropriate indexes.

The simplest way for the year and month is probably to use `format()`.  For instance:

```
      format(date(from_unixtime(post_time)), '%Y-%m') = format(curdate(), '%Y-%m')
```

Comment: that works perfect. I do have 1 question. How can I now make that work to get current month and current year?

Comment: @RandyThomas . . . I don't understand your comment.  `curdate()` gets the current date, which is the current month and year.  If you want the data from the current month/year, then ask another question.

Comment: I need to not only pull data from today (say it's the 11th day) but I need to pull data from the whole month (example January) and I also need another line to pull data for the current year (example 2017). I am trying to allow people to pick if they only want to see data for today, this month or this year. I hate to open up a whole new question for this when in the first question I did ask about today, month and year.